# How to compare and remove second element of a nested list using List comprehensions?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I have a nested list and would like to compare and remove a list inside a nested list based on the condition match.

Here is my code :

```
def secondValue(val):
    return val[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nestedList=[]
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        nestedList.append([name,score]) # Made a nested list from the input 
    lowestMarks=min(nestedList,key=secondValue) [1]  #Extracting the minimum score 
    newList=[x for x in nestedList[1] if x!=lowestMarks] # PROBLEM HERE
```

The last line of my code is where I want to remove the list inside my nested list based on condition match. Sure, I can do this with a nested for loop but if there is a way to do this using list comprehension I'd consider that approach.

Basically I'd appreciate an answer that tells how to remove a list from a nested list based on a condition. In my case the list looks like :

```
[[test,23],[test2,44],......,[testn,23]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems**:

- `for x in nestedList[1]` just iterates over second sublist of the nested list.
- `x` is a sublist and it can never be equal to `lowestMarks`.

Use a list-comprehension as:

```
newList = [[x, y] for x, y in nestedList if y != lowestMarks]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake was in the below line and is now fixed.

```
newList=[x for x in nestedList if x[1] != lowestMarks] # PROBLEM HERE
```

nestedList[1] fetches the second sub-list. You want to iterate over the entire list.

Comment: Thank you brother. Your help is appreciated. I am positive it will helps others who face this issue. :)